# USB behavior not as expected

Tags: usb, stm32, enumeration, packet

I am porting the USB driver from the STM32F4 device to STM32L4 device. It almost works. During the enumeration it sends and receives the information, but the data is not exactly the same as from the "plain" STM Cube generated project. II have the same settings in both project but get the strange results.

I lost a week trying to find the solution, maybe someone here had a similar problem and can help me out. Sorry for the images but there is no other of posting some informations on the SO

[image]

As you can see the packets are almost the same, but not identical. After 25th transmition the board stalls and accepts only very limited number of the requests

The both files form the wireshark (in the wireshark and text formats) are here:

https://gitlab.com/diymat/usb-problem/tree/master

The ep* files are form my port, stmcdc* - STM Cube generated one. Both were running using the same hardware.

Comment: Don't crosspost!

Answer (score 0):

Is it same  clock config ? 
Is 48MHz USb clk ok ?
Using non crystal or ext osc to get 48MHz USB commonly lead to issue on large xfer Even on F4 can't say for l4 
So it may appear to work  with hid and rather short packet but start mis-behaving for larger xfer

Answer (score 0):

So I would like to be of a bit better help, but I would definitely need more information to give you a good direction to head in. That being said, there could be a number of things wrong, so I will try to cover what I can think of. Let's start with some of the most obvious.

Clock configuration/hardware can be causing problems due to faulty components, or incorrect selection of software/hardware.  This can cause a number of issues, but this could be a symptom of that.

If you are using the generated FATFS middleware from ST, Small stack size inside of the configuration of the L4 can cause this exact problem.  it may work until the PC register receives an erroneous error which could lead to some sort of fault, or in some cases, just a bad result returned inside of the FATFS, or USB peripheral code from ST and it will return a dirty sector on the USB window read from the FATFS, which will result in terminated operations on the peripheral.

I see you're using STM32Cube, so you can edit stack and heap size by opening the file `startup_stm32l475xx.s`

and edit the two as you see fit for your application.

```
; Amount of memory (in bytes) allocated for Stack
; Tailor this value to your application needs
; <h> Stack Configuration
;   <o> Stack Size (in Bytes) <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
; </h>

Stack_Size      EQU     0x400

                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
Stack_Mem       SPACE   Stack_Size
__initial_sp


; <h> Heap Configuration
;   <o>  Heap Size (in Bytes) <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
; </h>

Heap_Size      EQU     0x200
```

Try increasing the stack size and see what happens.  Good luck on finding your solution!